# Programmatically add a browser payment method

Tags: google-chrome, payment-request-api

I was looking at the payment request API for web payments, and was wondering if it's possible to programmatically add a browser payment method.

I can add manually e.g. in Chrome via `Settings > Privacy and security > Autofill > Payment methods`, but would like to be able to do this programmatically.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about adding a new credit card information, it's not possible. However, adding a payment app is part of the standard Web Payments specifications and the added payment apps will appear there in the future.

For example, you can add one from here: https://bobpay.xyz/

There are only a few real payment apps out there yet, Web Payments working group at W3C is working hard at making it better and enabling the ecosystem.

You can learn more here: https://g.co/dev/WebPayments